# Is there a way to "teleport" in the iPhone version of Secret of Mana?

Tags: ios, secret-of-mana

In the original SNES version of Secret of Mana, there was [a really neat trick](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12433/2252) which allowed you to teleport your party to *almost any* other location in the game. By saving your gave in a *very specific* spot on the world map, switching to a different game (even a new game), getting to the location you wanted to teleport to, doing an in-game reset, and loading the original game, you would find your characters from the first game file at the location your second game was at when you performed the in-game reset.

I just tried on the iPhone version of Secret of Mana and this is not possible, because the island you have to land on to perform this trick has changed. It's shape is different and you can no longer land on it!

**SNES Version screen capture:**

[image: Screencap of island to land on]

**IPhone version screen capture:**

[image: Island is a different shape!]
[image: And you can't land on it!]

**Is there a way to perform this teleport trick on the iPhone version of Secret of Mana?**

Comment: Now I want to replay this so badly.  Are there any other (non-cosmetic) changes between the versions?

Comment: omg! Josh! Welcome back.

Comment: @badp Thanks! I'm only "semi-back", you won't see me in chat for a while yet :-) Also, I will argue to the death that this is a "feature" **not** a "bug"!!!

Comment: I do not have the game to test but another "trick" you could in the original, and would like to know if it can be done here is switch rapidly between controlled characters, each switch they moved forward a pixel. You could get past the guy blocking you from your hometown with this trick.

Comment: Sure, just like missingno was a feature

Comment: @Josh Good point, I should synonym the two.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I will check that for you.

Comment: How good is the control scheme? I've got a couple of other SNES/PSX games remade for the iPhone and results... *Varied*, from "painful to make my inner child weep" to "actually more usable than the original"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Nope, I am unable to make the select trick work.

Comment: @Shadur it takes a little getting used to. See the circle at the lower left of the screen? You put a finger in there and drag up, down, left or right instead of the D-pad. I found holding the iPad with two hands on either side and using my thumbs 9as if the whole thing were a controller) to work fairly Well. There's also updated graphics and dialog, it's a good port overall!

Comment: @Josh: I can verify the select trick doesn't work, it was one of the first things I tried after getting booted out!  I'm convinced there's no way to teleport on the iPhone without save hacking and the fact that they changed the layout indicates that they went to specific lengths to prevent it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Josh, it does not matter if you will argue to the death that this is a "feature" not a "bug", as it was clearly considered a bug by the developers. Also, from your description it really sounds like a bug to me personally.

Now, to adress your question itself: No, there is no known way to "teleport" your party like it was possible with that glitch.

Comment: To avoid argument, I'll accept this answer. Note that your claim that "it was clearly considered a bug by the developers" is completely unverified so I also have to downvote as well... I'll remove the downvote if you can link to a developer stating it was a bug.

Comment: I can't. I believe it was considered a bug due to the fact that it was there in the old version and isn't there in the new version. But, there's a not so small chance that, even if it was a feature, the developers decided against it when developing the game for this platform (as it is probable that was programmed again from scratch) or that the feature was never documented and they didn't know it was there in the first place.